# Why is my story board actions skipped when my trigger triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, storyboard

I have a Tabcontrol that I'm trying to add actions based on triggers.

Using Routed Events I can get my storyboard to trigger and the my actions respond as intended. Now I'm trying to prevent my storyboard actions from triggering for a specific tab header if that header is selected.

This has forced me to move away from routed events since I can't use a property condition and a routed event to determine if my storyboard will execute.

Fast forward and now I have finally been able to get IsMouseOver to respond as I wish to the mouse. (My background properties changes and changes back as the mouse enters and leaves the tabitem header. I'm almost there I think but as soon as I add the exact same storyboard as before my code decides to be lazy and skip it for some reason. The background setter is still being triggered but the storyboard remains silent.

I tried removing the setter but the storyboard still does not trigger.

End of the Day: I looking to set styles that transition nicely between each other for all possible combinations of Is Mouse Over and Is Selected.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tenant_Tool_Analytics_Module.Resources.Components"
                    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Tenant_Tool_Analytics_Module.Resources.Components">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:NavigationElement}">
        <Setter Property="Template">


            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:NavigationElement}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness=".7"  x:Name="Bd">
                        <Grid Width="150" Height="50" Opacity="0.75" x:Name="NavigationElementGrid">


                            <Grid.Background >
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="2.0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#006A4D" Offset="1.0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#56be88" Offset=".2"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush >
                            </Grid.Background>
                            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="NavigationElementText" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{TemplateBinding LabelText}" FontFamily="Futura XBlkIt BT" FontSize="12"/>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <!--
                    Trigger related to when the mouse is over the header
                        I would like it to Execute the doubleanimations 
                    -->
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                <!-- Missing condition: If selected = false -->
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <!-- Start BUG the bellow code does not execute -->
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>

                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NavigationElementGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NavigationElementText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="14" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <!-- End BUG -->
                            <!-- The triggers are fireing becuase this is being set. -->
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Blue"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <!-- 
                        When the mouse leaves I want it to return to it's original 
                        state. 


                        -->
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                                <!-- Missing condition: If selected = false -->
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <!-- Start BUG the bellow code does not execute -->
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NavigationElementGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To=".75" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NavigationElementText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="12" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <!-- End BUG -->
                            <!-- The triggers are fireing becuase this is being set. -->
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Red"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <!-- Missing two more MultiTriggers (very similar to above) for the cases of if the tab is selected.-->
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Code behind

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Tenant_Tool_Analytics_Module.Resources.Components
{
    public class NavigationElement : Control
    {
        public string LabelText
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(NavigationElement), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public object Icon
        {
            get
            {
                return (object)GetValue(IconProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(IconProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(object), typeof(NavigationElement), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


        public System.Windows.Media.Brush BackgroundColour
        {
            get
            {
                return (System.Windows.Media.Brush)GetValue(BackgroundColourProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(BackgroundColourProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColourProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColour", typeof(System.Windows.Media.Brush), typeof(NavigationElement), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

    }
}
```

Implementation code

```
<Window x:Class="Tenant_Tool_Analytics_Module.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tenant_Tool_Analytics_Module"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Tenant_Tool_Analytics_Module.Views"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Tenant_Tool_Analytics_Module.Resources.Components"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <views:HeaderView x:Name="HeaderView" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Left" TabStripPlacement="Left" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10">
            <TabItem Padding="0">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <controls:NavigationElement LabelText="Stacking Plan" Icon="{StaticResource StackPlanIcon}"/>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Button Content="HI"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Padding="0">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <controls:NavigationElement LabelText="Tenant Profile" Icon="{StaticResource TenantProfileIcon}"/>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Button Content="HI"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Padding="0">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <controls:NavigationElement LabelText="Submarket" Icon="{StaticResource SubmarketIcon}"/>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Button Content="HI"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Padding="0">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <controls:NavigationElement LabelText="Industry" Icon="{StaticResource IndustryIcon}"/>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Button Content="HI"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Can you please add a **short** sample ``MainWindow.xaml`` containing a `TabControl` and your `NavigationElement` so that we can copy-paste and test?

Comment: I've added the requested code section.

Comment: Thanks. Only now I'm a bit lost because I don't know which code I'm supposed to comment or uncomment in your style:p Can you please post the exact XAML that you wish worked without any commented parts? Of course you can leave some single line comments to help understand where it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I've removed the commend out lines of code and added descriptive lines of comments.

Comment: I'll edit my answer if you give more details about what you're trying to achieve for the `IsSelected` case:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you weren't aware of the fact that `MultiDataTrigger` objects have both `EnterActions` and `ExitActions`. Instead of having one `MultiDataTrigger` triggering on `true` with only `EnterActions` and another `MultiDataTrigger` triggering on `false` with only `EnterActions`, you can use only one `MultiDataTrigger` triggering on `true` with both `EnterActions` (to change the object to an abnormal state) and `ExitActions` to transition it back to its normal state.

The `Triggers` collection now works as expected and becomes, as a bonus, easier to read:

```xml
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
            <!-- Missing condition: If selected = false -->
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NavigationElementGrid"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     To="1"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NavigationElementText"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                     To="14" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackgroundBrush"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NavigationElementGrid"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     To=".75"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="NavigationElementText"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize"
                                     To="12"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackgroundBrush"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                        <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
    </MultiTrigger>
    <!-- Missing two more MultiTriggers (very similar to above) for the cases of if the tab is selected.-->
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Also notice how I've used a `ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames` to change the `Border.Background` property without needing a `Setter` in another `Trigger`. This way, all changes are performed in the same `Storyboard`. For this to work, you just need to assign a named `SolidColorBrush` to your `"Bd"` `Border`:

```xml
<Border.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BorderBackgroundBrush" Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>
</Border.Background>
```

To prevent the `Storyboard` to play if the ancestor `TabItem` is selected, I suggest you add a boolean `IsSelected` `DependencyProperty` to your `NavigationElement`, so that you can bind this property to its `TabItem` ancestor by adding a `Setter` in your `Style` like this:

```xml
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}}"/>
```

And you just have to add the condition in your `MultiDataTrigger` (but you already figured that out):

```xml
    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
```

***Sidenote***: I recommend you wrap and indent your XAML attributes to avoid long XAML lines that force you to scroll. Besides the increased readability, having each XAML attribute on a new line is more version control-friendly because one attribute change only impacts one line.

Comment: Thanks I'll be testing it out right now. For your question about the IsSelected. I would the behavior to also be dependent on if the tab is selected. Make it pop out a little more so it can be differentiated from just hovering over them. While at the same time no longer triggering this current storyboard for if the mouse if over or not.

Comment: I tested it out and it works like expected. Now I can continue and make it look "good". Thank you so much for your help. I will take your Sidenote into consideration, your code is much more readable.

Comment: i edited to add details on how to prevent the storyboard to play when the parent tabitem is selected. Hope that helps as well.